# group by picking columns with null value - mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query and want to group the rows and return groupped data but my query is not working as expected.

my query-

```
select item, branch, packunit,packlevel,dealqty,PromotionFlag,PromotionID, PromotionEndDate, cnc,delivery, volumedeal, standard_price_scheme,
deliv_price_scheme
from 
(
SELECT 
        `item` AS `item`,
        `branch` AS `branch`,
        `PackUnit` AS `PackUnit`,
        `PackLevel` AS `PackLevel`,
        `DealQty` AS `DealQty`,
        `PromotionFlag` AS `PromotionFlag`,
        `PromotionID` AS `PromotionID`,
        `PromotionEndDate` AS `PromotionEndDate`,
        SUM(`cnc`) AS `cnc`,
        SUM(`delivery`) AS `delivery`,
        SUM(`volumedeal`) AS `volumedeal`,
        `standard_price_scheme` AS `standard_price_scheme`,
        `deliv_price_scheme` AS `deliv_price_scheme`
    FROM
    (
SELECT DISTINCT
        `Pricing_Today`.`item` AS `item`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`branch` AS `branch`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`price_scheme` AS `price_scheme`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`PackUnit` AS `PackUnit`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`PackLevel` AS `PackLevel`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`DealQty` AS `DealQty`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`PromotionFlag` AS `PromotionFlag`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`PromotionID` AS `PromotionID`,
        `Pricing_Today`.`PromotionEndDate` AS `PromotionEndDate`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`Pricing_Today`.`PriceType` = 'C&C') THEN `Pricing_Today`.`Sell`
        END) AS `cnc`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`Pricing_Today`.`PriceType` = 'Delivery') THEN `Pricing_Today`.`Sell`
        END) AS `delivery`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`Pricing_Today`.`PriceType` = 'Volume Deal') THEN `Pricing_Today`.`Sell`
        END) AS `volumedeal`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`Pricing_Today`.`PriceType` = 'C&C') THEN `Pricing_Today`.`price_scheme`
        END) AS `standard_price_scheme`,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                ((`Pricing_Today`.`PriceType` = 'Delivery')
                    OR (`Pricing_Today`.`PriceType` = 'Volume Deal'))
            THEN
                `Pricing_Today`.`price_scheme`
        END) AS `deliv_price_scheme`
    FROM
        `Pricing_Today`
        where item = 78867
        and branch = 0
    GROUP BY `Pricing_Today`.`item` , `Pricing_Today`.`PackUnit` , `Pricing_Today`.`PriceType`,`standard_price_scheme`,`deliv_price_scheme`
    ) as a

    GROUP BY branch,`item` , `PackUnit`,`standard_price_scheme`,`deliv_price_scheme`
    ) as a
    -- group by item, packunit
```

which returns -

[image]

BUT, when I group by item, pack I get this -

[image]

for cnc its showing null values. How do I eliminate null values and get the numbers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take aggregates of the `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    p.item,
    p.branch,
    p.price_scheme,
    p.PackUnit,
    p.PackLevel,
    p.DealQty,
    p.PromotionFlag,
    p.PromotionID,
    p.PromotionEndDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.PriceType = 'C&C'         THEN p.Sell END) AS cnc,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.PriceType = 'Delivery'    THEN p.Sell END) AS delivery,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.PriceType = 'Volume Deal' THEN p.Sell END) AS volumedeal,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.PriceType = 'C&C' THEN p.price_scheme END) AS standard_price_scheme,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.PriceType = 'Delivery' OR p.PriceType = 'Volume Deal'
             THEN p.price_scheme END) AS deliv_price_scheme
FROM
    Pricing_Today p
WHERE
    item = 78867 AND branch = 0
GROUP BY
    p.item,
    p.branch,
    p.price_scheme,
    p.PackUnit,
    p.PackLevel,
    p.DealQty,
    p.PromotionFlag,
    p.PromotionID,
    p.PromotionEndDate;
```

This is just a standard pivot query.  The idea behind taking the `MAX` of a `CASE` expression is that if a given group of records has a single non `NULL` value, then `MAX` would correctly extract it.  This works because `MAX` ignores `NULL` values.

Note that I removed the backticks from your query, none of which were necessary.  I try to avoid using backticks unless they are really needed, because it makes the query harder to read.